# problemas con la configuracion de ssl en nodejs

Tags: nodejs, openssl

Estoy intentando de instalar una libreria en un proyecto concretamente bitcoinjs-lib y obtengo una serie  de errores que atribuyo a alguna errata en la configuracion del ssl.

```
michel@michel-H81M-DS2:~/programacion/bitcoinjs-examples$ npm i bitcoinjs-libnode: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)

> tiny-secp256k1@1.0.1 install /home/michel/programacion/bitcoinjs-examples/node_modules/tiny-secp256k1
> node-gyp rebuild

node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)
node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by node)
gyp: Call to 'node -e "require('nan')"' returned exit status 0 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-43-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/michel/programacion/bitcoinjs-examples/node_modules/tiny-secp256k1
gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN bitcoinjs-examples@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN bitcoinjs-examples@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! tiny-secp256k1@1.0.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the tiny-secp256k1@1.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/michel/.npm/_logs/2019-01-16T12_58_03_653Z-debug.log
```

Alguna idea de por donde puedo seguir?, he googleado y probado con varias cosas pero no consigo dar con ello.

Comment: ¿Has instalado openssl desde el fuente?

Comment: no recuerdo haber tocado nada del openssl creo que es la instalacion que trae ubuntu por defecto , algo se ha trastocado con algun paquete de nodejs, el caso es que no me deja instalar nada